# Select Custom Taxonomy from Theme Options

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-options

I have been trying to get a drop down of my custom taxonomy terms to show up in my theme options page but with no luck. I looked a several posts here and followed the tips but the code just does not display the taxonomy terms.

```
/** Seasons */
$season_terms = get_terms('season');
$season_tax = array();
if( $season_terms ) {
    foreach( $season_terms as $season ) {
        $season_tax[$season->term_id] = $season->name;
    }
}

array_unshift( $season_tax, 'Choose a Season' );
```

I get the "Choose A Season" option and then a blank option for each of my terms ( two at the moment ). What could be causing this? I am stumped on this one???

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Since you are likely developing this and you don't have any posts associated with the `season` taxonomy, you will not get any terms returned with `get_terms('season');' unless you specify the parameter`hide_empty`to be`0`. I would change the code thusly:

```
    /** Seasons */
    $args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0' );
    $season_terms = get_terms('season', $args);
    $season_tax = array();
    if( $season_terms ) {
        foreach( $season_terms as $season ) {
            $season_tax[$season->term_id] = $season->name;
        }
    }

    array_unshift( $season_tax, 'Choose a Season' );
```

By default, terms are only returned if they are associated with at least one post. Check out the `hide_empty` parameter on this page for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thanx, I tried that with no luck. Ended up having to move the theme-options into an included file and added it as a menu page. Now it works just fine.

Comment: works for me.  i'll have to remember that unshift trick.